# Excel: Sum series of function calls

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following simple function that I need to call *n* times and sum the result.

```
10000*((1.01)^n)
```

I wish to call this 30 times, with *n* being 1-30, then sum the result. How can I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following array formula.

```
=SUM(1000*((1.01)^ROW(A1:A30)))
```

Paste the formula into the formula bar and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  It doesn't matter where you enter the formula or what the contents of `A1:A30` are; the `A1:A30` is just a trick to get Excel to iterate through the formula 30 times.

Comment: Or just use the formula for a sum of a geometric series `=(1.01^31-1.01)*100000`

Comment: @lori_m Yes, or that!  You should really post that as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a few years, but I just stumbled across this today, 5-29-17.  Here is the correct formula:  sum=10000((1-1.01^31)/(1-1.01)-1)=351327.  I verified this result with brute force in Excel.  James Kane

P.S.:  I tried to comment on the above two answers, but it would not let me because I am new here.  The issue with the first answer is a typo (should be 10,000 not 1,000).  The second answer also has a typo (should be 10,000 not 100,000) and an incorrect formula.