# Excel sumseries and Apple Numbers compatibility

Tags: excel-formula, apple-numbers

I need to calculate the total tuition to estimate the needed savings. That is, the tuition -now- is 10.000€, the estimated inflation is 2%. How much tuition is going to be paid in 10 years during four years?

Using the trick [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12334597/11498), I can obtain the correct amount... in Excel.

```
{=SUM(Tuition*(1+Inflation)^ROW(OFFSET(A1;YearsToTuition;0):OFFSET(A1;YearsToTuition+YearsofTuition;0)))}
```

Now, the thing is, this has to work in Apple Numbers and I don't know if that'll work.

So, the question is whether there's another form to implement this in Excel.

**Edit:** I use Excel, my client uses Numbers.

**Edit:** I ended up using the FV function [as proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26564492/11498) by thecraw.

```
=FV(Inflation;YearsofTuition;-Tuition*(1+Inflation)^YearsToTuition)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but is the question you are asking the following.

I want to calculate a total amount of savings that I need today that will be pay for 4 years of tuition which I will start in 10 years. The cost today is 10,000 a year inflation is 2% per year.

If this is the question you could do it with 4 cells in numbers or excel by using the formulae =(10000×(1.02^10))for the first year change the 10 to 11 for the second year etc. This will give you   12189 for first year 12433 for second 12682 3 year and 12936 for the last year as the tuitions starting 10 years down the road. So if I have understood what you are trying to do, today you would 50242 to pay for this but that is assuming you are getting 0 return on this money for the 10 years and you just have it sitting there making nothing to pay for this. Anyway my best guess as to what you were asking.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a good idea (in my situation), but I would like to know if there's a formula that does this calculation.

Comment: Yes there are in both excel and numbers there are all the base financial functions. The fv (future value) function basically does exactly what I described in my answer. You use it 4 times once for each of the years.  Numbers can import excel so if you use its formulae the other person should be able to import it into numbers. Some stuff may not work but that one probably will. You then may want to use PV on these once you figure out what your return would be on this money over 10 years and bring them all back todays date. All standard finance functions are supported in both.

Comment: Cool. I looked at FV, but I can't get it to work. Back to the drawing table.

Comment: I ended up using FV with the base tuition calculated with the formula and then having the function calculate 4 years. See, the number of years until tuition and the number of years of tuition are variable. Thanks.